Exporting summary.betareg and summary.gam from list to csv
I have two types of models (GAM and beta regression) that I am running for my data and I am using a lapply function to iterate over multiple variables. I am encountering an error when trying to export result summaries into a csv. Reproducible example below
library(mgcv)
library(betareg)

data(mtcars)
vars <- names(mtcars[c(2:11)])
vars

models = lapply(vars, function(x) {
  gam(substitute(i ~ s(mpg) , list(i = as.name(x))), 
      method = 'REML',
      data = mtcars)
})
y=lapply(models, summary)
names(y) <- vars # To add names of the model instead of list number
df=purrr::map_df(y, broom::tidy, .id = 'vars') 
write.csv(df, "results/summary.csv")

The map_df and tidy method work for standard linear models.
df=purrr::map_df(y, broom::tidy, .id = 'vars')  but not for summary.betareg or summary.gam list
I have also tried df=as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,y)) which is closer but still not quite right.
Is there a way to extract these summaries easily?

Have you already tried without calling summary first? i.e. using y=models works fine. And in case of a linear model broom::tidy will give the same df for both the "raw" model object and summary(model).

No I had not tried that and you are right this is correct! Thank-you

@stefan Post as an answer?

The issue is that broom does not provide a tidy method for objects of class summary.gam whereas for linear models aka models of class lm we have both a tidy.lm and a tidy.summary.lm method. While the implementation of the methods differ slightly, tidy.lm calls summary and you should get the  same df from both methods.
And the same holds for tidy.gam. As with tidy.lm it calls summary under the hood. Hence, there is no need to use summary and you could achieve your desired result by calling tidy on the "raw" model object, i.e. use y <- models:
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.9-1. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.


vars <- names(mtcars[c(2:11)])

models <- lapply(vars, function(x) {
  gam(substitute(i ~ s(mpg), list(i = as.name(x))),
    method = "REML",
    data = mtcars
  )
})
y <- models
names(y) <- vars
df <- purrr::map_df(y, broom::tidy, .id = "vars")

df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#>    vars  term     edf ref.df statistic    p.value
#>    <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 cyl   s(mpg)  4.57   5.56     34.7  0         
#>  2 disp  s(mpg)  2.54   3.17     34.4  0         
#>  3 hp    s(mpg)  3.05   3.80     16.9  0.00000130
#>  4 drat  s(mpg)  1.00   1.00     26.0  0.0000180 
#>  5 wt    s(mpg)  2.32   2.91     38.1  0         
#>  6 qsec  s(mpg)  1.00   1.00      6.37 0.0171    
#>  7 vs    s(mpg)  1.00   1.00     23.7  0.0000345 
#>  8 am    s(mpg)  1.00   1.00     16.9  0.000285  
#>  9 gear  s(mpg)  1.00   1.00      8.99 0.00540   
#> 10 carb  s(mpg)  1.00   1.00     13.1  0.00109

And just as reference, for a simple linear model we get the following outputs when applying tidy to the raw model object and the output of ´summary()`:
model <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)

broom::tidy(model)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  30.1       1.63       18.4  6.64e-18
#> 2 hp           -0.0682    0.0101     -6.74 1.79e- 7


broom::tidy(summary(model))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)  30.1       1.63       18.4  6.64e-18
#> 2 hp           -0.0682    0.0101     -6.74 1.79e- 7

